# Parameter not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

This script not work properly. I want to print value in parameter of url `file:///C:/Users/laddi/Desktop/new%201.html?t=vindu&b=thind`

```js
    function GetURLParameter(sParam)
    {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
    }      
    var tech = GetURLParameter('t');
    var blog = GetURLParameter('b');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="value is " + blog+  "   "+ tech;
```

```html
    <html>
     <body>
    <a id="demo"></a>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: `window.location.search.substring(1);` < what is this supposed to do? have you tried to `console.log` or `alert(sPageURL)`? Because this seems like a very strange action to me, which should be returning an empty string, meaning everything you do afterwards is being done on an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get your parameters from the string:

```
'file:///C:/Users/laddi/Desktop/new%201.html?t=vindu&b=thind'
```

```js
function GetURLParameter(sParam, str)
{
sParam = sParam.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + sParam + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
results = regex.exec(str);  
if(!results)
{
console.log('no param')
}else
{
console.log((results[2].replace(/\+/g, " ")))
}
}
var tech = GetURLParameter('t', 'file:///C:/Users/laddi/Desktop/new%201.html?t=vindu&b=thind');
var blog = GetURLParameter('b', 'file:///C:/Users/laddi/Desktop/new%201.html?t=vindu&b=thind');
```

Comment: Though the script in this example may work, it doesn't really 'include' the OP's handling of the function and doesn't explain what it does or why...

Comment: I don't know where he is getting that string from, this will let them hard code it or pass it from wherever they are getting.

Comment: that's a totally fair point. I was actually talking more about he looks for a specific parameter and returns it. Your function doesn't return anything and doesn't look for a specific param. That's all I meant by it haha.